# Shell Script for commenting a line

Tags: shell, sed

I want to comment a line where ever this condition comes

> if(a & b)? c:d;

so i have seen one script,but its not working.

```
for f in var.c; do
  cat $f | sed 's@if(a & b)\(.*\)$@/*\1 */@' > converted-files/$f
done
```

Can any one tell me the better script than this which will work for my circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

Your `sed` expression is written to *include* only the part after the ternary operator.  Try:

```
sed 's@if(a & b).*$@/* & */@'
```

That said, I'm not sure if you really want to use *regex* to comment out code.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be using `cat`.  Your code fragment is not valid C, either, but that may be a good reason for commenting it out.

```
for f in var.c
do
    sed 's@if(a & b).*$@/*&*/@' $f > converted-files/$f
done
```

You can add spaces around the comment markers if you prefer, but symmetry suggests either 0 or 2 spaces in total, not just 1 as in your script.